# SAS: simple way to predict future sales

Tags: sas, predict

I have data looking like this:

```
>   Data sales;
>     Infile datalines missover;
>     Input year $ month  sales;
>     Datalines;
>     2016 1 489
>     2016 2 475
>     2016 3 523
>     2016 4 546
>     2016 5 675
>     2016 6 667
>     2016 7 334
>     2016 8 359
>     2016 9 521
>     2016 10 526
>     2016 11 459
>     2016 12 439
>     2017 1 500
>     2017 2 445
>     2017 3 531
>     2017 4 541
>     2017 5 620
>     2017 6 630
>     2017 7 300
>     2017 8 350
>     2017 9 502
>     2017 10 524
>     2017 11 402
>     2017 12 469
>     ;
```

I wish to take the average increase the last year, say, and use this to predict month for month next 12 months. I'm not looking for an advanced method, this is purely programming for me.

So far, what I have is this (too ugly):

```
    data sales2;
set sales;
lag_sales=lag(sales);
diff=sales-lag_sales;
start_month=month(intnx("month",today(),-12));
start_year=year(intnx("year",today(),-1));
if year>=start_year and month>=start_month;
run;
proc sql;
create table sales3 as
select avg(diff) as avg_diff
from sales2 ; quit;
proc sql;
create table sales4 as
select year, month, monotonic() as row_no, sales, avg_diff,
       sales+avg_diff*monotonic() as sales_pred
from sales2, sales3
;
quit;
```

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Your original question was clear enough, no need for down vote, I will up vote you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below answers your question / what you are trying to do. 
Note that I used:

- Retain method instead of the Lag function,
- Observation number instead
  of montonic().

This will improve your query performance if you have a lot of records

Please note that you can also predict the sales based on a moving average rather than just the difference(not included in code).

**Code based on you sales dataset:**

```
/*Calculate the difference*/
data diff;
set sales;
row = _n_;
retain prev;
if row=1 then do; prev=0; diff=0; output; prev=sales;end;
else do; diff=sales -prev; output; prev=sales; end;
run;
/*select avg for 2016, for live data feed change to -1*/
proc sql noprint;
select avg(diff) into:avg from diff where input(year,4.)=year(today())-2;
quit;
/*select avg for 2017, for live data feed remove the -1*/
proc sql;
create table sales_new as
select year,month, sales, &avg as avg_diff, Sales+&avg as sales_pred from diff where input(year,4.)=year(today())-1;
quit;
```

**Difference Table:**
[image: Diff]

**Output:**

[image: Output]